# Tomcat oracle wallet configuration. How to add oraclepki.jar to classpath

Tags: java, oracle, tomcat

I am following below guide to add oracle wallet support to my Vaadin webapp.

https://sysapp.wordpress.com/2010/08/31/how-to-oracle-wallet-with-jdbc-thin-driver-datasource-tomcat/

But, I get following exception in my application.

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: PKI classes not found. To use 'connect /' functionality, oraclepki.jar must be in the classpath: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/security/crypto/core/RSAPrivateKey
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:70) ~[ojdbc6.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "11.1.0.7.0-Production"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:133) ~[ojdbc6.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "11.1.0.7.0-Production"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:199) ~[ojdbc6.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "11.1.0.7.0-Production"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:263) ~[ojdbc6.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "11.1.0.7.0-Production"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:271) ~[ojdbc6.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "11.1.0.7.0-Production"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.getSecretStoreCredentials(PhysicalConnection.java:2626) ~[ojdbc6.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "11.1.0.7.0-Production"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.parseUrl(PhysicalConnection.java:2394) ~[ojdbc6.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "11.1.0.7.0-Production"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.readConnectionProperties(PhysicalConnection.java:1932) ~[ojdbc6.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "11.1.0.7.0-Production"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:489) ~[ojdbc6.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "11.1.0.7.0-Production"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:203) ~[ojdbc6.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "11.1.0.7.0-Production"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:33) ~[ojdbc6.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "11.1.0.7.0-Production"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:510) ~[ojdbc6.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "11.1.0.7.0-Production"]
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38) ~[tomcat-dbcp.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:255) ~[tomcat-dbcp.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2303) ~[tomcat-dbcp.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2289) ~[tomcat-dbcp.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2038) ~[tomcat-dbcp.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1532) ~[tomcat-dbcp.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111) ~[spring-jdbc-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77) ~[spring-jdbc-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    ... 55 more
```

Exception says to add `oraclepki.jar` (found in oracle client distribution) to classpath. I tried to add it to classpath by below methods.

- Add `oraclepki.jar` to `$CATALINA_HOME/lib`
- Add `oraclepki.jar` to `$CATALINA_HOME/webapps/<my_extracted_war>/WEB-INF/lib`
- Add to classpath using `CLASSPATH` environment variable.

None of the above actions made any change.

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Have you edited java.security file? And added oracle.security.pki.OraclePKIProvider before sun Provider?

Comment: @ArkadiuszŁukasiewicz Yes I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to add two more jars to `$CATALINA_HOME/lib` and then it worked.

All necessary libraries are following:

- osdt_cert.jar
- osdt_core.jar
- oraclepki.jar

Above jars are found in full Oracle Client distribution (and not Oracle Instant Client for example).

Location of libraries in oracle client installation: `$ORACLE_HOME/jlib`